# Early stopping and the sklearn neural_network.MLPClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, perceptron

I am using [`sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html). I am using the `early_stopping` feature, which evaluates performance for each iteration using a validation split (10% of the training data by default).

However, my problem is multi-label. According to the API, validation uses subset accuracy, which is very harsh for multilabel problems.

**Is it possible to define an alternative scoring function (ideally mlogloss) to be used in validation?** Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use sknn rather than the sklearn implementation of MLP. That allows use to add our own valid_set and specify the loss function. Details [here](http://scikit-neuralnetwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_mlp.html#classifier).